# Appending on text file not working

Tags: ios, swift, file-handling

just like the answers here on SO, I'm trying to append a text file. My code goes like this:

```
if countdownTimer > 0 {
   let dir = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first!
   let fileurl = dir.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

   let date = NSDate()
   let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
   let hour = calendar.component(.Hour, fromDate: date)
   let minutes = calendar.component(.Minute, fromDate: date)
   let seconds = calendar.component(.Second, fromDate: date)

   newLine = "\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds),\(someValue),\(someValue)\n"

   let data = newLine.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!


   if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileurl!.path!) {
      do {
          let fileHandle = try NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL: fileurl!)

          fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
          fileHandle.writeData(data)
          fileHandle.closeFile()
       } catch {
          print("Can't open fileHandle \(error)")
       }
   } else {

    }
        countdownTimer -= 1
}
```

The difference on my implementation is that I am creating the file on separate event (and I'm sure that the file exists before appending) and appending the text file is inside a timer which loops every second. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write code that will help you to understand where you could make a mistake.

Firstly create `Error` types and file name where we going to log our info.

```
let file = "logger1.txt"

enum Throwing: Error {
    case impossibleToWrite
    case impossibleToRead
}
```

Than two functions that will `writeToFile` and `readFromFile`.

```
func writeToFile(file:String, log: String) throws {

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

        do {
            let writer = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: path)
            writer.seekToEndOfFile()
            writer.write(log.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            writer.closeFile()
        }
        catch {
            throw Throwing.impossibleToWrite
        }
    }
}

func readFromFile(file:String) throws {

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

        do {
            let text = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(text)
        }
        catch {
            throw Throwing.impossibleToRead
        }
    }
}
```

Than small loop that will iterate and create log with date. Usage of the try! is bad practice but for test purpose it is ok.

```
func logTimeInLoop() {

    for _ in 0..<10 {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS "
        let text = formatter.string(from: Date()) + "\n"

        try! writeToFile(file: file, log: text)
    }

    try! readFromFile(file: file)
}
```

This is output of the data in the file.

[image]

Comment: first of all, thanks for the response. I've tried implementing your sample code (with minor revisions to remove the syntax errors) but I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: @Cuevas what is the problem ? You are running my code example ? If yes it will append all data\

Comment: yes, I'm running your code but when I look at package contents and browse to the generated file, there was no info. It's really weird because for example, here's a different implementation (I collect info, concatenate it on some variable, create a log file with the variable, all info will be printed) but in this case, it does not.

Comment: Print path and go by this path to the folder there will be file

Comment: I already saw the file, it is there, but with no contents inside.

Comment: I test this and all data is in the file. Are you sure that you are using my code example ?

Comment: Hey Oleg, my bad. I've mistyped a bit that is why it is not appending. It's working now, thanks!

Comment: I am glad to help